# Почему не работает show() hide()

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте пожалуйста помогите на сайте есть кнопка меню при нажатии на нее выдвигается меню так вот проблема в том что если нажать на кнопку меню один раз все ок если нажать второй раз он скроет меню а вот если нажать кнопку меню 3 раз он выдвинет меню и сразу же его скроет почему?

```
    <script>
        function hideDiv(){
            $(document.body).click(function (){
            if ($(".mobile:first").is(":hidden")){
                $(".mobile").slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $(".mobile").hide("slow");
            }
        });
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: http://bodydelight.kz/ вот где я это делаю можно посмотреть если уменьшите немного окно браузера появится кнопка меню

Comment: Нужно добавить в вопрос HTML код, необходимый для [создания минимального, полного воспроизводимого примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: А по поводу того, что меню работает "не так": при каждом вызове `hideDiv` функции у вас добавляется новый обработчик `click` события для `body`. Это очень плохая затея, приводящая к различным негативным последствиям. Если, конечно, где-то в другом месте кода эти обработчики не снимаются.

Comment: А что за псевдокласс :first? Имелось ввиду css'совский :first-child или .first() от jq?

Comment: @Regent        Пожалуйста не могли бы вы подсказать как лучше сделать?

Comment: @sepgg [документация по :first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: @МихаилВолков мог бы, если бы в вопросе был пример (со свойствами, описанными выше). И код бы поправил, и вопрос бы отредактировал, чтобы он смотрелся хорошо.